# SQL Window function using Case

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I am trying to return records where the ID and status can be the same as long as the Paid Date is different.  If an ID has multiple statuses then it needs to return only one record with the order priority of Approved, Denied, Pending, First Notice.  However, if an ID has multiple Approved statuses with different dates then it needs to return both records.

```
   select *, row_number()over(partition by id, paid_date order by
                              CASE when status ='Approved' then 1
                                   when status = 'Denied' then 2
                                   when status = 'Pending' then 3
                                   when status = 'First Notice then 4 end                                            
                                          ) as rownum
   from @t
```

This is how the final output should appear:

```
   ID     Paid_Date      Status
   1      2020-01-01      Approved
   1      2020-02-01      Approved
   2      2020-02-03      Approved
   3      2020-02-04      Denied
   4      2020-02-04      Denied
   5      2020-02-05      Approved
```

Here is some sample data:

```
   declare @t table(id int, paid_date date, status varchar(25))

insert into @t
values(1, '2020-01-01', 'Approved'),
(1, '2020-02-01', 'Approved'),
(1, NULL, 'First Notice'),
(2, '2020-02-03', 'Approved'),
(3, '2020-02-03', 'Pending'),
(3, '2020-02-04', 'Denied'),
(4, '2020-02-04', 'Denied'),
(5, '2020-02-05',  'Approved'),
(5, '2020-02-05', 'Approved')

select * from @t
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.  I feel like I'm close but can't get to the end.

Comment: I don't see in your expected results any column other than the table's columns? Why do you have row_number() in your query?

Comment: The first 2 records have the same ID and status, but different dates.

Comment: I updated the question to be more specific.

Comment: My mistake.  The record should be Denied, not Pending.

Comment: The issue is a null Paid Date should not always be excluded.  It just happens in this example that the record to be excluded has a null Paid Date.  I think the null date is what's causing the issue with my not solving this.

Comment: Row(3, '2020-02-03', 'Pending') is excluded because an ID with multiple rows and different dates should only return multiple rows if they are both Approved.  If one is Pending and one is Denied then it should choose the Denied.  I excluded the record with the null date because it is not Approved.  It is not excluded because of the null date but because of the status.

Comment: I updated the query.  I meant to use Order By.

Comment: @Dale K--this seems to work great.  I don't know if I could have ever come up with this solution.  Thank you!

Comment: I clicked on the answer being useful.  Is there anything I else I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Add a second `row_number` to detect the multiple approved but different date case e.g.

```
with cte as (
    select id, paid_date, [status]
        , row_number() over (partition by id order by
            case when status ='Approved' then 1
            when status = 'Denied' then 2
            when status = 'Pending' then 3
            when status = 'First Notice' then 4 end asc
        ) as rownum1
        , case when [status] = 'Approved' then row_number() over (partition by id, paid_date order by paid_date) else null end as rownum2
    from @t
    where paid_date is not null
)
select id, paid_date, [status]
from cte
where rownum1 = 1 /* Highest priority as defined */ or rownum2 = 1 /* Or approved but different date */
order by id, paid_date, [status];
```

Returns:

| id | paid_date | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | Approved |
| 1 | 2020-02-01 | Approved |
| 2 | 2020-02-03 | Approved |
| 3 | 2020-02-04 | Denied |
| 4 | 2020-02-04 | Denied |
| 5 | 2020-02-05 | Approved |

Answer (score 0):

Hmm . . . I think your logic is basically correct with two tweaks:

- remove the date from the `partition by`.
- Explicitly select all "approved".

So:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id 
                                order by (case when status ='Approved' then 1
                                               when status = 'Denied' then 2
                                               when status = 'Pending' then 3
                                               when status = 'First Notice' then 
                                          end)   
      from @t t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 or status = 'Approved';
```

Comment: Needs to be approved with **different** dates :)